# Prove the existence of countable unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I recently picked up the elementary set theory and I have reached the concept of sequences. The text then asks to prove the existence of the **the set of all finite sequences of elements of a set**, i.e., for any set $A$, the set, $$\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb N}A^n$$ exists.

Further, if this does exist, I suspect that countable union of existing set also exist. Can anyone prove this?

I tried to prove that there is such a set $S\in \mathbb N$ that $\{A^n | n \in S\}$ exists, and $0 \in S$, $n \in S$ implies $n+1 \in S$, so that together with the axiom of union the prove is complete. But I failed to construct such a set.

BTW, the farthest axiom I have reached is the axiom of infinity that basically grants the existence of inductive set. So it would be helpful if a proof given is based on that and anything before (axiom of union, power set, schema of comprehension, pair, existence and extensionality).

Comment: You probably mean $S=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:A^n exists\}$, otherwise $S$ is defined in terms of itself.

Comment: @Chrystomath You are right, but this way I cannot prove that existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each sequence is a subset of $A\times \mathbb N$. So take the power set of $A\times \mathbb N$, then use separation to pick out the sequences.

Comment: You are so correct... I thought about this but concluded that finite sequences do not belong to $A\times \mathbb N$... only to miss that they were actually subset of it. But I think it is more precise to say for each sequence $s$, $s \in A^n \subset A \times \mathbb N$.

Comment: So can you prove or disprove the existence of countable union of existing set?

Comment: @AstrickHarren All unions exist by the Axiom of Union.

Comment: Axiom of Union needs $\{A_n | n \in \mathbb N\}$ to exist first, where $A_n$ can be any set. But that existence is not trivial because the set of all sets simply doesn't exist?